# Rails 3 Capybara error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, testunit

I'm trying to get Capybara to work with rails 3 (and test unit) but when I try to run `rake test:integration` I get an error:`ArgumentError: @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request`

**The test**:

```
require 'integration_test_helper'

class UserNotesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "User should login" do
    user = Factory.create(:user)
    visit '/login'
    assert_response :success

    fill_in 'user_email', :with => user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'

    assert_redirect_to notes_path
  end
end
```

**integration_test_helper:**

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'capybara/rails'

module ActionDispatch
  class IntegrationTest
    include Capybara
  end
end
```

I'm not really sure whats going wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a problem with capybara not assigning anything to the `@request` variable after `visit`.

One solution is to use the rails built-in methods, i.e.

```
get '/login'
assert_response :success
```

In rspec, i use assertions on `page` rather than `@request`.

There is [some discussion here.](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rspec.user/16391)

Comment: Official explanation for your issue: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/240